# boost.future causing problems with clr

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, clr

I am using visual studio 2012 with a clr library that needs to link to a native library.
My library which is using boost::future.

I am having this problem when I use future::then(F &&) function against the managed project:

```
Error   910 error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which        should, but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef: (dummy): (0x0100003e).  D:\ClrProject\somefile.obj
```

I tried, as suggested in other questions, to make the `dummy` types in the library complete, since I cannot forward declare a nested struct from inside a template, as can be done with `boost::thread::dummy` struct.

This did not solve the problem.

My setup is the following:

- Boost 1.55.
- Using boost .dlls.
- define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
- define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
- define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION

I am using these very defines on the dependent .dll as well, to make sure that all parts of the API are exposed correctly.

Comment: Just don't compile Boost code with /clr in effect.  Or switch it off on-the-fly with #pragma managed.  The C++/CLI compiler can only translate C++03 code to MSIL.  Post a snippet if you need more help.

Comment: It won't work, unfortunately. I tried to use the same #define's in both my dll and the /clr dll that consumes this library. I tried to #pragma managed the .cpp file that uses boost::future, and still, the typeref problems stays there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

@Hans Passant your suggestion was right. I just wasn't putting the `#pragma` the correct way.

I had to put the pragmas so that my headers are compiled as unmanaged code. Once that was done, it seems that template instantiations for my code were emitted as unmanaged. At that point, problems disappeared.

So what I did is something like this:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "MyHeaderWithFutures.h"
#pragma managed(pop)

void f() {
   //
   f = myObject.Something().then(...);
}
```